# Can Oracle TimesTen (or 12c's In-Memory) benefit from GPU?

Tags: oracle, in-memory-database, timesten

I have looked into TimesTen and In-Memory recently. They claim they use [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (Single instruction, multiple data) to speed up queries. We use HP DL380 G9 Servers for our DB. Since This series are limited to the Intel Core architecture, It can't benefit from more than 64 CPU cores (32 physical w/ hyperthreading) which Linux kernel 4 (Oracle Linux 7) can provide, opposite to the AMD64's HA which scales fine.

The question is: Can Oracle utilize some sort of GPU parallelism on the box, as OpenCL2 allows shared memory architecture? Is there a way to define GPU cores or compute units as processing units for Oracle?

Comment: If you're planning on mining cryptocurrency like Ethereum on the server, sure.  Not for the DB applications though.

Answer (score 2):

Any application that uses GPUs for processing has to be custom-written to access the GPU's processing power.  Where GPUs shine are in floating point arithmetic, something that is low on the list of database operations, so no, no database software is likely to harness GPUs for processing.

Comment: Granted that GPUs are great at floating-point operations, yet where they shine is the SIMD and some flavors of MISD (D&C scenarios) flows and architecture which are essential to databases. Same as database engines, good at repetitive tasks and somewhat bad on control flows.

Comment: Good points.  But I doubt Oracle will venture into using GPUs as the majority of their clients would not have access to servers with GPUs powerful enough to harness.  They used to support dozens of operating systems but now it is basically Windows, Linux, and Unix that are supported.